# How long does the ubuntu installation take and what to do after it?

Tags: installation, wireless, kernel

I've got a HP probook 4515s, AMD Sempron SI-42 (2,1 Ghz), ATI Radeon HD 3200, only 1GB ram.

I'm installing Ubuntu 12.04 with a CD right now, and it seems to take about 20 minutes since.

And its also my first time I use ubuntu and I wanted to know how to set up wlan ( a friend told me it doesnt work on my pc)
And maybe a link to a site telling my which things I need to install and what I should know and stuff.

Comment: Question like this that are open ended should be posted on the http://ubuntuforums.org/. | About WLAN: That will work. | 20 minutes for installation is a good estimation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It usually takes anywhere between twenty to forty minutes on a reasonable computer(Your computer should take about this long), but if you have a slow internet connection, you can press `Skip` below when it says that it is downloading files as these files are not important. Once it is installed, you need to reboot into your regular installation and connect your computer to your wireless router or modem *with a cable* to install Wi-Fi drivers.'

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `softwre-properties-gtk`. Click on the icon below with the box and the globe. Check the box saying:

> Proprietary drivers for devices [restricted]

and give your password.

Now, click the top icon on the launcher bar on the left, and type Terminal to search for it. Click on the icon for **Terminal**(The icon is a black box with some characters on it).

Now, wait for a prompt that should look something like `user@computername:~$`, and type *exactly*:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

When it asks for a password, type *your* password. Note that *it will not be seen*. You won't even see stars or dots. When you have typed your password, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It do some things, download things from the internet(remember, you are using the cable)

Once you see the `user@computername:~$` prompt again, type *exactly*:

```
install bcmwl-kernel-source -y
```

Let it process, and once you get the `user@computername:~$ prompt`, you can reboot your computer, disconnect the cable, and connect to your WiFi network. As to what you should install, feel free to browse the **Ubuntu Software Center**.

While all comments have been removed(or will be), a full transcript is available [here (text)](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1139379/) or [here (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipwmd.png).